# why delete() function is not deleting the value after filtering the collection in magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to delete a data from the table.

I am using this code snippet

```
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {  
                $cat->delete();
        }
```

and it is deleting the complete table.

but I dont want to delete the complete table so I filter the data with some attribute and tried this code

```
$categoryModel= Mage::getModel('blog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('article_id', $articleId);  
        foreach ($categoryModel as $cat) {
                $cat->delete();
        }
```

but it is not deleting anything.
How can I delete the data according to some field.

Comment: Is `$articleId` the primary key of your table? Did you prove that your `delete` loop is really entered?

Comment: @JürgenThelen `$articleID` is not the primary key of my table that is why i am filtering the record according to field name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This code for delete Your artical From category.

```
foreach ($categoryModel as $catId) {
                $blog = Mage::getModel('blog/category')->load($catId);
                $blog->delete();
            }
```